# How to addGroundOverlay below streets

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I add this texture to the map and it was not too hard. But I can't figure out how I would go about making them stick below the buildings and streets. I would prefferable want to color them diffrently!

How could I do that? If it is at all possible...

```
GroundOverlayOptions overlay = new GroundOverlayOptions();
       overlay.image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tex_grass));
       overlay.position(latLng, 64, 64);
       overlay.transparency(0.5f);

map.addGroundOverlay(overlay);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Ground Overlays (and also Tile Overlays, Markers, Polygons, ...) are drawn on top of the base map.

You can only control the `zIndex` that controls the order in which the ground overlay is drawn with respect to other overlays (although always under the Markers)